# X-Send File и NGINX

Tags: apache, nginx

Есть модуль апача - *X-Send File*, с помощью которого скачиваются файлы с сайта:

```
header("X-Sendfile: ".realpath($route));
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$name."\"");
```

Но когда поставил *NGINX*, скачивание работать перестало:

Когда я иду по адресу `http://site.com/download/?id=95`, пишет что на 80 порту:

```
The requested URL /index.php/download/ was not found on this server.
```

Что нужно подправить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

у *nginx* есть [аналогичное средство](http://wiki.nginx.org/X-accel) под названием `X-accel`.

скорее всего, в вашем дистрибутиве это средство включено по умолчанию.

тогда, согласно [документации](http://wiki.nginx.org/XSendfile):

1. надо описать `location` (например, `download`) как `internal`:

   ```
   location /download/ {
     internal;
     root   /путь/к/каталогу;
   }
   ```

   файлы будут браться из каталога `/путь/к/каталогу/download/`.

   если нужен путь без окончания `download`, то `location` должен выглядеть так:

   ```
   location /download/ {
     internal;
     alias   /путь/к/файлам/; # обратите внимание на слэш в конце
   }
   ```

   тогда файлы будут браться из каталога `/путь/к/файлам/`.
2. заголовок надо заменить: вместо `X-Sendfile` должно быть `X-Accel-Redirect`.
3. обратите внимание на возможную ошибку в конфигурации, разобранную [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/431780/178576).