# Скачивание файла с помощью X-Accel-Redirect

Tags: php, nginx, download

*NGINX* пишет `not found`, когда я пытаюсь скачать файл с сайта `http://site.com/download/?id=95`

папка `/_files` лежит на уровень выше `/www`, т.е.

тут скрипты:
`/site/www/`

а тут файлы:
`/site/_files/`

В папке `/_files` могут быть подпапки.

Конфиг сайта

```
server {
    listen *:80; ## listen for ipv4
    server_name site.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access-site.log;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:88/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_connect_timeout 120;
        proxy_send_timeout 120;
        proxy_read_timeout 180;
    }

    location /download/ {
       internal;
       alias /var/sites/site/_files/;
    }


    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|webp|ico|css|bmp|swf|js|html|txt)$ {
        root /var/sites/site/www;
    }

}
```

Скрипт который скачивает файл

```
header("X-Accel-Redirect: /download/".$route);
header("Content-Type: application/x-force-download");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file."\"");
```

В итоге заголовок выглядит так

```
X-Accel-Redirect: download/content/95/arch.rar
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: в `error.log` что пишет `nginx`? кстати, путь в `X-Accel-Redirect: download/content/95/arch.rar` по идее, должен начинаться со слэша: `X-Accel-Redirect: /download/content/95/arch.rar`

Comment: убедитесь, что получаемый путь верен. в приведённом примере это: /var/sites/site/_files/content/95/arch.rar

Comment: В лог ничего не попадает. Вот вывел все заголовки в скрипте X-Accel-Redirect: /download/content/95/f0rest-DWI5kGNNPWaO-file.rar; 
Content-Type: application/x-force-download;
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="f0rest-DWI5kGNNPWaO-file.rar" Алиас такой: alias /var/sites/site/_files/; Получается, в итоге он будет обращаться по такому пути (как я понимаю download меняется на алиас):
/var/sites/site/_files/content/95/f0rest-DWI5kGNNPWaO-file.rar. Этот путь верный, но все-равно not found.

Comment: 1. может быть, логирование ошибок в nginx вообще не включено? (в приведённом отрывке его нет). 2. может быть, *not found* возвращет *apache*, а не *nginx*? надо посмотреть в логах *apache*. 3. попробуйте для теста как в [примере](http://wiki.nginx.org/XSendfile) обойтись без дополнительного пути: чтоб в заголовке было `/download/файл`.

Comment: 1. Логгирование включено. 2. В логе апача так же нет ничего как и в nginx. 3. Для теста как в примере, как я сделаю так, если путь к файлу формируется в скрипте php? у папки _files/ есть своя структура под-папок как я написал в шапке

Comment: 1,2. так кто же вам тогда возвращает 404-ю ошибку? 3. попробуйте запросить файл, который лежит непосредственно в каталоге `/var/sites/site/_files/`

Comment: вот [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5547197/4827341) и [здесь](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/issues/2454) в `location` нет завершающего слэша. попробуйте `location /download` вместо `location /download/`.

Comment: 404 - 100% выдает nginx. Но в лог ничего не пишет! Насчет слэша по всякому пробовал - не работает. Я не пойму, почему в логах нет ошибки нигде..

Comment: Сделал лог в дебаг режиме, в шапку прикрутил

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25157/discussion-between-alexander-barakin-and-sanu0074).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

проблема оказалась в попытке использования внутреннего (`internal`) `location`-а `/download` в качестве внешнего (для ссылок из внешнего мира вида `http://site.tld/download/...`).

внутренним этот `location` является по требованиям самого `nginx`-а для корректной работы механизма `X-Accel`.

решается проблема переименованием `location`-а в какое-нибудь точно неиспользуемое имя. например:

```
location /intenal-download {
  internal;
  alias /путь/к/файлам;
}
```

и одновременно надо возвращать соответствующее значение в заголовке `X-Accel-Redirect`. основываясь на приведённом примере, примерно так:

```
header("X-Accel-Redirect: /internal-download/".$route);
```

обратите внимание, что путь в заголовке должен начинаться со слэша.